# OpenErp and Dynamics Ax: how is programmable and customizable OpenErp?

Tags: odoo, axapta

i'm trying to compare OpenERP and Dynamics AX. Does anyone can tell me the difference when programming OpenErp and Dynamics AX? For example, I know that in Dynamics AX exists a customization layer, and also, all objects are hierarchical and programmable (and customizable). 
Do exists this type of concept in OpenERP ? Can i personalize it in a modular way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used Dynamics AX, so I can't compare them. I have written several custom modules for OpenERP, and their extension model works reasonably well. It's a bit unusual, so it takes a while to learn. They just released a description of their [plans for version 7](http://www.openerp.com/node/1107), and it sounds like the inheritance model will become much more standard.

If you want to learn more, look at the developer book's [chapter on developing modules](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_1.html). Particularly important concepts are [object inheritance](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#object-inheritance-inherit) and [inheritance in views](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_3.html#inheritance-in-views).

Answer (score 1):

yes and yes: any OpenERP object from a (standard) module can be extended and customized in another specific / local module.

This includes:

- customizing the fields definition (adding / hiding / redefining)
- customizing the views and forms
- customizing the workflows
- ...